# jquery ajax fire and forget

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to fire some requests to php using ajax. I do not need a response from these and would like to kill the ajax request right after it has been sent. this way I can fire more ajax calls without hitting the 6 ajax call limit. I have googled this and none of the options seem to work.

I have tried using the .abort() command but it will kill the request before it reaches php.

what is the best way of doign this?

basically i want to run this code and have the ajax response either return immediately or kill it off die, while the php function on the other end continues to process.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api/v1/restart/" + val,
    success: function(xhr) {
     }
});
```

I do not need a response back i just want it to kick off the php function.

Comment: question doesn't make a lot of sense as it is written. Please show your code attempts along with expanded explanation

Comment: Maybe take a look into [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets)?

Comment: I am currently using websockets to return data from my php function. i need something to kick off the api call on click, which is why I am using ajax.

Comment: Have your php fire off some other method that it won't have to wait on (such as a curl with a timeout of 1ms) then immediately return to the browser so that the browser isn't sitting around waiting for some task that it doesn't care about to complete. The abort part of your question doesn't make sense because you clearly don't want to abort it. You also don't need a success callback. I would create a sample but I don't know how to solve this in php without doing my own research.

Comment: Are you trying to daemonize your PHP script?

Answer (score 3):

Example: Request the test.php page, but ignore the return results.

```
$.get( "api/v1/restart/" + val );
```

Example:  Request the test.php page, but ignore the return results, so simple !!

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

and if you want to bypass the maximum calls limit just use `.queue()`

http://learn.jquery.com/effects/uses-of-queue-and-dequeue/

Comment: could you give an example of how queue could be used with this? thta is exactly my issue I am being limited to 6 so I would like the ajax to return so another can start.

Answer (score 1):

just to make the queue answer clear , cause posting it in a comment will not be clear :

// jQuery on an empty object, we are going to use this as our queue

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});



$.ajaxQueue = function( ajaxOpts ) {
    // Hold the original complete function.
    var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

    // Queue our ajax request.
    ajaxQueue.queue(function( next ) {
        // Create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue.
        ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
            // Fire the original complete if it was there.
            if ( oldComplete ) {
                oldComplete.apply( this, arguments );
            }
            // Run the next query in the queue.
            next();
        };

        // Run the query.
        $.ajax( ajaxOpts );
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in parameter list of the ajax call. Also make your php request Asynchronous

```
async: true
```